# how to remove duplicate values from a list but want to include all empty strings from that list

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have a list of objects in which I want to remove duplicates but does not want to remove blank objects. 
I am using DistinctBy lambda expression. But it also removes duplicates.
Can anyone help me in providing the condition that passes blank and checks only that object which has proper value in an object ?

Comment: where is your code buddy?

Comment: @viveknuna: Maybe you can be his 'code buddy'

Comment: You say objects but you mean a list of strings right?

Comment: He says empty strings in the title so I would suppose so

Comment: @EpicKip possibly. But you wouldn't use `DistinctBy` on a list of strings. (but rather `Distinct`)

Comment: Yes but I doubt if OP knows that, its barely a question as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a very simple extension method:

```
    public static void DistinctKeepingEmptyStrings(this List<string> list) {
        var support = new List<string>(list);
        HashSet<string> knownValues = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var aString in list) {
            if (aString == "" || knownValues.Add(aString)) {
                support.Add(aString);
            }
        }
        list.Clear();
        list.AddRange(support);
    }
```

Comment: If you only have to use this once, an extension method is not the way to go (in my opinion). But of course this can be used on itself too (not as an extension method)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

var list is in this case a list consisting of all duplicates (minus the empty strings)
then I just iterate through the duplicates and remove them from the listOfValues.

```
List<string> listOfValues = new List<string> {"test", "test2", "", "test2", "", ""};
var list = listOfValues.GroupBy(r => r).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1)).Where(r => r != "");
foreach (var aVar in list)
{
    listOfValues.Remove(aVar);
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt the count need to check for greater than 0? If one exists its not going to be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: If one exists it isn't a duplicate is it?

Comment: But just thought to myself after typing that this wont work because you're modifying the collection, so @Roma's answer is better :)

Comment: Aren't you modifying a list while iterating over it? I think this would crash.

Comment: I was as I said. Fixed it.